# Removing the focus frame box from controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I have a WPF application with various controls in it. When I move between controls using TAB, I can see the focus frame box:

[image]

Is there any way to hide this frame, so it won't be seen? A WPF solution is preferable but a WIN32 method would be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
```

CheckBox example

```
<CheckBox FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something app-wide but based on your answer I searched SO and found out I am not in luck. Still, this helps.

Comment: Guess you found this link. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/141c8bfa-f152-4f8a-aca0-3c3b5440d183/. And if Dr. WPF says that there's no great way to affect all of your controls than I'm not gonna argue :)