# Button how to remove border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a question about dat wpf buttons.
In my app I have fore example some code

```
<Button x:Name="SukaKnopka" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Black" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="20" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Image Source="ButtonsImages/close_btn.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Button>
```

All is fine but there is some little border around this button =( I have tryed `BorderBrush="{x:Null}"`
but the border again present. (This border highlights if MouseOver)

Comment: Have you tried setting `BorderThickness="0"` and `BorderBrush="Transparent"`?

Comment: Try to override the Controltemplate of the button and remove this border or trigger it differently on mouse over if needed.

Comment: Issues like this are better investigated when you show a screenshot of the problematic area.

Comment: this exact question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899948/get-rid-of-button-border-in-wpf

Comment: Did you try that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117891/removing-the-focus-frame-box-from-controls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slade is right, try modifying what you have to look more like the following and it should give you what you want.

```
<Button x:Name="SukaKnopka" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Black" MaxHeight="20" MaxWidth="20" BorderBrush="Black">
<Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
            <Image Source="ButtonsImages/close_btn.png" Stretch="Fill"/> 
    </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it, a lot of WPF controls are fully defined in their styles. So even if you specify a different border on a `Button`, for example; the `Button`'s existing styles will override whatever you have specified. To overcome this, you must create a [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx).

Comment: Styles accept changes to their properties being applied, however - so you can still change aesthetics of a control without having to completely rewrite a full style or template; granted, some of the brushes, etc. might be used regardless of specifications.

Comment: Aye, but the `Button` in particular is essentially over specified in that a lot of the triggers will override any custom styling - i.e. when hovering the mouse over the `Button`.

Comment: Agreed. For this specific problem, though, I'm sure the solution should be more straightforward.

Comment: this is actually true for a lot of basic controls like the button or checkbox. more often than not, especially when you have something simple in mind the template is easier

Answer (score 2):

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
```

This should do the trick. It will set every BorderThickness or every Border inside the button to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I did any "real" WPF, but does

```
BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
```

work?

Comment: I just tried this in Kaxaml, and it doesn't make any difference -- it looks like Button's template ignores BorderThickness.